Determine the maximum positive integer $m$ such that $x_n(x_n − 1)(x_n − 2). . .(x_n − m + 1)/m!$ is never a multiple of $7$ for any integer $n$.

The sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3, . . .$ is defined by $x_1 = 2022, x_{n+1} = 7x_n + 5$ for
all positive integers $n$. Determine the maximum positive integer $m$ such that
$x_n(x_n − 1)(x_n − 2). . .(x_n − m + 1)/m!$
is never a multiple of $7$ for any positive integer $n$.

This question is part of the New Zealand Math Olympiad Round $2$ and I have posted this question to seek a solution, helping both me and future students who come across this question in the future.
Anyways, here is how I started:
First, we notice that $m ≤ 2022$. Otherwise, $x_1(x_1 − 1)· · ·(x_1 − m + 1)/m!
=
2022(2022 − 1)· · ·(2022 − m + 1)/m!
= 0$, and $0$ is a multiple of $7$.
Then, since $x_n ≥ x_1 = 2022$ for all $n$, we can write
$(x_n(x_n − 1)· · ·(x_n − m + 1))/m!$ =
$(x_n(x_n − 1)· · ·(x_n − m + 1)(x_n − m)(x_n − m − 1)· · · 1)/(m!(x_n − m)(x_n − m − 1)· · · 1)$
= $x_n!/m!(x_n − m)!.$
I am stuck from here onwards, if anyone could provide a solution, I would appreciate it very much! Thank you.

I am assuming the result can't be 1, correct? or 2022(resulting from setting m=2021)? Why are they not a good fit?

Do you know modular arithmetic? If you look at the sequence modulo $7$, the problem becomes much easier

Let $O(a)$ be the exponent of the higher power of 7 that divides $a!$. What can you say about $O(a+b) - O(a) - O(b)$? When is this equal to 0? $\quad$ Essentially the question wants us to find the largest $m$ such that $O ( x_n) - O( x_n - m) - O(m) = 0 $ for all $n$.

As you've already determined, we can write the expression as
$$\frac{x_n!}{m!(x_n - m)!} = \binom{x_n}{m} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Regarding the power of $7$ in the binomial, Kummer's theorem states that

... for given integers $n \ge m \ge 0$ and a prime number $p$, the $p$-adic valuation $\nu _{p}{\binom {n}{m}}$ of the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{m}$ is equal to the number of carries when $m$ is added to $n − m$ in base $p$.

Thus, for \eqref{eq1A} to never be a multiple of $7$ means that there can't be any carries when $m$ is added to $x_n - m$ in base $7$. Using positional notation, i.e., the subscript $7$ to indicate the digits are representing the number in base $7$, we have
$$x_1 = 2022 = 5\times 7^3 + 6\times 7^2 + 1\times 7^1 + 6 = 5616_7 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Since $x_{n + 1} = 7x_{n} + 5$, similar to how multiplication by $10$ in base $10$ works, this means each next value, in base $7$, is the previous one shifted to the left by $1$ position and with a $5$ added on the right. As such, the next several $x_n$ values are
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_2 & = 56165_7 \\
x_3 & = 561655_7 \\
x_4 & = 5616555_7 \\
\ldots
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Let $j$ be the exponent of the largest non-zero digit in the base-$7$ representation of $x_n$, with $d_i$ being the base-$7$ digits of $x_n$ and $e_i$ being those of $m$, i.e.,
$$x_n = \sum_{i=0}^{j}d_{i}7^{i}, \;\; m = \sum_{i=0}^{j}e_{i}7^{i} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
If $e_i \gt d_i$ for any $i$, then for the smallest such $i$, the $i$'th digit of $x_n - m$ would be $7 + d_i - e_i$, so then when $m$ is added to $x_n - m$, the sum of the $i$th-digits would be $7 + d_i$, requiring a carry for it to then become $d_i$. However, if $e_i \le d_i$ for all $i$ instead, then the $i$'th digit of $x_n - m$ would be $d_i - e_i$ and, thus, there would be no carries when $m$ is added to $x_n - m$.
Thus, the largest possible $m$ is where each of its base-$7$ digits are the minimum ones among all of the $x_n$. The right-most digit minimum is $5$. Also, the minimum of the next $3$ digits to the left is $1$ due to it starting in the second right-most position in $x_1$, and then being moved to the left for each higher index. For all of the remaining left-most digits, the minimum is $0$ since $x_1$, as shown in \eqref{eq2A}, has only $4$ non-zero digits. Thus, the largest possible value of $m$ is
$$m = 1115_7 = 7^3 + 7^2 + 7 + 5 = 404 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

As an aside, one doesn't need the full strength of Kummer's theorem, though it is useful to be aware of. My comment was getting them to think about $ \sum \lfloor \frac{ a+b} { 7^i } \rfloor$, from which it follows that we need no carry over.
